# Facebook App Invide V4.0 Notification

Tags: ios, facebook, push-notification

I upgraded my apps (iOS and Android) to the new Facebook SDK (V4.0) to use the Facebook app invite. (See https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/app-invites).

My problem: when I send an invitation to a Facebook friend he gets a notification if he is using an Android device, but he doesn't get one if he is on iOS (even if he normally receives notifications from Facebook). Despite that, in both cases I can find the invitation in the Facebook app. So the problem is just about the notifications.

Do you know if Facebook has not implemented this part of their API or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on the Facebook developer advocacy team and can help answer this for you.

The best way to test this is to use test users. The reason is that we don't send a push notification if we think the person has installed the app. If you use test users, it should work.

Comment: @pschang I tried with test users and I don't receive any notifications. You have any idea ?

Comment: @wassimboy How can i use test users for Facebook app invite feature?

Comment: @Hiren I have followed steps described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users. Hope it will helps you

Comment: Used Test User in both devices.. made them friends. Uninstalled the app in one device. Invited other device to use the App. Still I can't get the notification. I only get notification in profile>apps>appInvite> ... not in the notification tab. Any help?

Comment: same issue I am getting, I can see the app invite in profile>apps>appInvite>..., but I can not receive the push notification.

Comment: I have created two test accounts and tried with that but still no luck.