# Facebook App Invites iOS SDK v4.0 configuration and states

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have recently started to implement the new [Facebook's App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios) feature. The invite is sent, but my friends (or app testers in my case) whom I sent app invites to did not receive any notification.

==

**Update**: I have successfully tested out the feature. But there are something to note, see my self-accepted answer below.

==

Having followed the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios), but I don't know if anything is misconfigured or how to debug the process.

So my questions are:

1. Does app invites feature needs an actual **App Store** app ID to be configured in the [App Link](http://applinks.org/) meta header tag? Because, as far as I understand this feature, the main purpose of this is to **recommend** my friends to try out an app that I like. The app I working on is still under development, and I see that the **App Store ID** field on App Link generator tool is `optional`. So I think when I shared an development app to my friends, they wouldn't receive the messages.
2. In the callback of of current `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
   [delegate methods](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate/), specifically
   `appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults:`, what kind of `Invite
   Sent` success result should I received when the invite is actually sent?
   Because, currently as I tested, when the invite is sent from
   `Facebook`'s app `invites` dialog, if I press `Send` and if the
   sending process success, the above delegate will only return boolean
   value of `1` for `didComplete` key. Not sure if `didComplete` is that the
   invite was sent to the receiver, or does it meant 
   `didFinished`?

*Side note related to (2.)*: In recent [App Invite introduction video at F8](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152800554083553), at 18:47, there was an indicator with an letter with "Invite Sent!" text below. When I tested out, I didn't see that. Could this be a (nice) beta feature?

Comment: Hi Did you find out what was in the success results for appInviteDialog:didCompleteWithResults ?

Comment: Hi, you can just add an logging to the delegate result. Normally, if we came  back to our app just by pressing the *Cancel* button in the Facebook App Invite sheet, there will be an additional key `completionGesture` in the `result`  dictionary. So if to want to check for success result (user did sent invite), you can use [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/vinhnx/817fe5de3dd5c88e491e). From there you can show a success HUD or something to indicate the success result.

Comment: Thanks @vinh  - for some reason the invite never succeeds when I test it - the progress bar gets to around 25% before failing.

I was really hoping to get something in the delegate callback to advise which users had been invited - my app needs some reference to this in order to set up a community - as I am unable to get a list of all the users facebook friends (my app is not a game or utilising facebook canvas) I was hoping the invite friends would be a useable alternative - kinda sucks that games have preference to utility apps :(

Comment: I think in your case, when sending invites fails, you might want to check if your AppLink is setup correctly. https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, after some research. To recap, in order to test the [**App Invite**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios) on your development app, there are something to note:

- **First and foremost**: The first you have to do before implement the app invite feature is that you have to upgrade your project's Facebook iOS SDK to latest version 4.0. So more work to **[migrate](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x)** from 3.x to 4.x

> To send app invites you must use version 4.0 or later of the Facebook
>   SDK for iOS - [see the note here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)

- The best way is to test with your **Testers** accounts, who has access to app in development mode (If you don't have, you can add your test Facebook user in Roles tab in your Facebook app dashboard).
- Your should test with both users on **Facebook's native mobile app (NOT simulator/device mobile browser)** in order to see your invite **push notification**. But first, check whether the app you want to send is **installed** on your mobile before or not; if it is not installed, you should received push notification (see comment from FB developer advocate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376536/1477298)).
- **Last but not least**: make sure you configure both your app correctly, [the steps are very minimal](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#app_links) and easy to follow, make sure there is not any typo in your scheme and your invite code.

Comment: hey thanks for sharing this recap. I followed this steps but I still not receiving notification. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I followed steps described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) and my app link works fine. I don't understand why my test user didn't receive notification (not push). Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I can't test this functionality in development environment. If I don't give an 'iPhone Store ID' I don't receive notification ...

Comment: Hmm... I think that's normal! Because in order to be tested in debug mode and later used in production mode, app must be configured on developer portal.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Apple Developer portal to be exact. Glad my recap helps you.

Comment: I forgot to precise that with the prod app, notifications works but not push. Wired ?? I passed an entire journey looking for explanations to figure this out, but no results

Comment: My app is configured in the Apple Developer portal. There is a particular configuration for this case ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: Did you test on mobile? The app which you are inviting had been installed before?

Comment: Yes I tested on mobile. Yes it has been installed before

Comment: I think you can delete the app and try again.

Comment: When the app is installed I don't receive notification and when I deleted I receive notification, but no push notification.

Comment: If my informations are good, I can send invitation to my friends with the app installed and when they click on the invitation it opens the app, it's for this reason why we config the app to handle deep linking, no ?

Comment: Also **live App ID** from iTunes Connect **must be filled** in in Facebook App settings.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: @VinhNguyen , Why did you removed "viewing on desktop would show nothing"? 
Wasn't it true.?

Comment: @ZaidPathan Hi, I removed that part because I realized I was mentioning about receiving [push notification on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29385325/revisions). And if you head to Facebook web on desktop, you would normally see the app invite notification in the right panel :)

Comment: @VinhNguyen , Sorry but I didn't find invite notification in browser.

Comment: @wassimboy How did you solved the problem with push notifications? I don't receive push notifications but I receive facebook notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question here and answered it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929118/4888794

Basically, the notifications only appear in the Facebook Mobile App and not on the FB website.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!

Your should test with both users on Facebook's native mobile app (NOT simulator/device mobile browser) in order to see your invite notification, viewing on desktop would show nothing.

Really on desktop I did not have invitations but on device got it!