# FBSDKAppInviteDialog in Facebook iOS SDK version 4.0.1 invite successfully sent, but no notifications received

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

With the new Facebook SDK 4.0.1, I have implemented below in my "Invite to App" button:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/1111111111"]];
content.previewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someImage.jpg"];

[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

By clicking the button, it successfully direct me to my Facebook app, I could pick my friends and type invite message, and the invites are sent (with a success tick at the end of the progress bar).

When I check `appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results`, the result is `didComplete = 1`. However, I could not see any notifications on my friends Facebook (which have not installed my app) or on Test User account Facebook. I am deeply frustrated with this, so any help is much appreciated.

A few more questions, I have put in my appID in the Facebook generated applink although my iOS app is still in development. Do I need a released valid appID for the applink to test the app invite function on Facebook? And does my Facebook app need to be reviewed and approved to test the app invite function with my friends? Thanks.

Comment: Your app needs to be live for other people (non admin/dev/test user) to be able to see it.

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can visit the link below. i have the same problem and this must help

[Facebook App Invites iOS SDK v4.0 configuration and states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383395/facebook-app-invites-ios-sdk-v4-0-configuration-and-states)

1. You invited Facebook user who already used your app
2. Must be a live Apple App id in App Setting Facebook
3. If user already installed your app. you can assign them as a tester then they always receive your notification.

Hope this help :)

Comment: getting error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 9.)"

Comment: Pls see question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331116/ios-facebook-app-invite-error

Comment: how to check for the app is not yet on appStore.

Comment: hi.. can you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802803/facebook-app-invites-notification-not-working-in-ios. Please help me If you can.

Answer (score 12):

After a few hours of also not seeing the invite notifications, I realized that the notifications only appear in the Facebook mobile app (**not on the FB website**).

Comment: i dont know how they did this, but istagram invite showed on facebook website and opens instagram.com

Comment: Instagram is facebook's app :)