# iOS Facebook app invite: error

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-invite-friends, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have to implement Facebook invite in my iOS app.
I am following below reference link: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios

and
created app link as per below link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

I am facing below error:-

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 9.)"
```

in below **FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate** delegate method

```
func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("didFailWithError: \(error)")

}
```

My plist setting is [image]

My code is as given below:

```
@IBAction func btnInviteClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var content: FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/MyFacebookAppLinkURL")

    //Optional
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = NSURL(string: "AnyImageURL")
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showWithContent(content, delegate: self)
}
```

Pls suggest any solution, to show invite pop up and work successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Me too also facing same issue if you find any issue let me know.

Comment: Have you created `appLinkURL` for your app?

Comment: Did you guys find out the solution?

Comment: I know this is pretty old post, but has anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: I am in same boat? anyone found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` in your AppDelegate. I've spend two days while trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't created an appLinkURL as @Rumin suggested in the comments, you can create them and make sure they work here https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host.

When you have your app links ready, make sure you have your app working with the latest App Transport Security restrictions made in iOS 9 and also whitelisting the other Facebook apps, follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9.

Comment: yes, I have created appLinkURL using https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host link. Facing issue- does not getting notification on Facebook.