# FBSDK 4.7.0 and iOS 9 Invite friends not getting notification

Tags: ios, facebook-invite-friends, fbsdk

My application is already live and I am updating it for iOS 9. So I am updating FBSDK. Everything is working fine while inviting friends.It opens the dialog box,choose the friends for invitation but I am not getting any notification.
Here is my code:

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/711720725626059"];
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

Can someone give me any suggestion or extension regarding the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit the link below. i have the same problem and this must help

[FBSDKAppInviteDialog in Facebook iOS SDK version 4.0.1 invite successfully sent, but no notifications received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484815/fbsdkappinvitedialog-in-facebook-ios-sdk-version-4-0-1-invite-successfully-sent)

1) You invited Facebook user who already used your app

2) Must be a live Apple App id in App Setting Facebook

3) If user already installed your app. you can assign them as a tester then they always receive your notification.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable suggestion.I have made some changes in facebook app settings and now getting notifications :)

Comment: @ShashankMishra "Happy Coding"