# iOS : Not receiving facebook App invites

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I'm trying to send app invitation to my facebook friends using below code
Everything works fine but friends are not able to receive any notification from my Facebook app invite.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/myappid"];
    //optionally set previewImageURL
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg"];
    // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    FBSDKAppInviteDialog *inviteDialog = [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Comment: follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484815/fbsdkappinvitedialog-in-facebook-ios-sdk-version-4-0-1-invite-successfully-sent

Comment: also i've had some issues because my App on Facebook wasn't Canvas app(only configured for iOS and android) - so people only were receiving notifications to the mobile Facebook app, not desktop.

Comment: @quarezz for my issue : is your iOS app live? they are saying if app is live then only friends will receive notifications. in content.appLinkURL what kind of url you are providing?

Comment: @BhushanVU yes, it was live at that moment. Can't give you much details though, it was some time ago and I don't have the account settings anymore.

Answer (score 4):

After a few hours of also not seeing the invite notifications, I realized that the notifications only appear in the Facebook mobile app (not on the FB website).

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: For me it doesn't show on Facebook mobile app either. Is the app supposed to be life for app invite to work?